# Store components in ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, loops, arraylist, addition

I want to store components like JButton, JTextField, JTextArea etc. all in same ArrayList and later loop through it and add every component to JFrame. I tried storing them in ArrayList but when I looped through it and added every component it included to my frame, nothing showed up in frame. Does anyone know how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you kindly post your code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Extending your question, I am wondering if there is a way to add all JComponents "at once" to JFrame using the List. Is it possible? If yes, would it be faster than placing one-by-one? I know we are probably talking about less that milliseconds for 100s of Components. Asking more out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the `ArrayList` like this:

```
List<JComponent> = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
```

The above works because `JComponent` is a common ancestor for `JButton`, `JTextField`, `JTextArea` - that is, it's a super class common to all JComponents.

It's not clear to me: why do you want to add the components first to an `ArrayList`? add them directly to the `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

go ahead with this:

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();

    components.add(new JButton("test1"));
    components.add(new JButton("test3"));
    components.add(new JButton("test3"));

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    for(Component component: components)
        frame.getContentPane().add(component);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

- add a layout manager to your frame
- call `pack()` to resize the frame according to your components
- set the frame visible

Comment: Just an extra comment for the poster of this question: This works thanks to the `FlowLayout` which supports a dynamic number of components, and to which you can add components without specifying constraints and they will all show up. With other layout managers it might not be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to use Layout Managers?

> A layout manager is an object that implements the LayoutManager interface* and determines the size and position of the components within a container. Although components can provide size and alignment hints, a container's layout manager has the final say on the size and position of the components within the container.

[Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't but it is something im working on hard to learn, so far without success. I have tried it like million times but never got components to go where i want them to go.

Comment: You could try NetBeans if you need a gui builder:
[NetBeans features - Swing GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)

Comment: I'm already using NetBeans, but I think that the code it generates is way too complicated for me to understand yet.